# Reading txt file in bash line by line, without knowing its name

Tags: bash, input

I need to read a file given to me in a script i made, the file can be any name, the input is as follows

> ./Naloga1.sh tocke < somefile.txt

This is the code i have:

```
while read line
do
  echo $line
done <
```

The problem is, firstly if i put the script name at the done, it will read all the lines in my file - the last one.
And secondly how can i acess the files name to then output it?
If i echo $1 $2 $3, $1 comes as tocke and $2 and $3 dont exist

Comment: Remove `<` after `done` to read from stdin.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`<` isn't an argument to the script, `bash` interprets that before your script is invoked.  It redirects `stdin` for the script to come from, in this case, `somefile.txt`.

So you don't have to redirect anything to read from the file inside your script, it can just read from `stdin` because the shell has already handled the input redirection for you.

If you want to take the name of the file as an argument, just remove the `<` from your invocation and then the string `somefile.txt` will be stored in `$2`, which you can use to redirect input for your while loop if you like or any other purpose you might have.

Comment: Thanks, do you maybe know how i would go about ignoring lines that start with "#"

Comment: Within the loop you could do something like `if [[ "$line" =~ ^# ]]; then continue; fi` to see if it starts with `#` and continue the loop if it does

Comment: Regular expressions could solve that problem or just add in an if validating the first character that you've read in. Echo into a tmp variable, check the first char, if not # insert it.